# CTE to Select in Chunks?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I would like to use a SQL Server 2008 (recursive?) CTE to select 1 million rows at a time of a 400 million row table. The results will be written out to a text file, which I grok but not the CTE chunking part.

The table has good covering indexes on a DateTime column but no PK.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: There is awfully insufficient information here. Give the exact table structure, indexes, and what is the desired result. There are just about one million ways to select chunks from an arbitrary table, using or not using CTEs, recursive or non-recursive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a psuedo PK by using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY <column>) as PK_Key`  windowing function but this will be suboptimal because the entire table will be ordered for each select.

A better way to do it is to chunk your statement by the indexes you have instead of on exactly 1m rows.  That is, examine some of your data and pick an arbitrary limit which achieves what you want.  If you have roughly 1m rows in a month, then for each data retrieval operation, get a months worth of data.  You won't even need a CTE for it, as from the sounds of it you aren't dealing with recursive data structures.

Comment: I like the idea of chunking by pre-existing index. There is a clustered index on 3 columns that is the same in every table. However, when I move past my test table there are millions of rows in each table. So I'm interested more in "fire and forget" than anything else, so chunking on an arbitrary number like one million is a decent best-bet (data will be BCPd later).

Comment: Well, you could always add a step that gets the TOP 1m rows ordered by <index desc> and then use the min and max ranges of the index to determine your "chunking factor"